# AVCapturesSession - capture video, microphone and background audio

Tags: ios, audio, video, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I need the same behaviour as seen in SnapChat, but for a longer duration.

I already have an AVCaptureSession that records video and audio from the built-in microphone.

What I need is to also record music running in the background, i.e. from Spotify, Apple Music etc.

I assume there is two parts to this:

1) Setting the correct category on AVAudionSession (in order to allow background music while recording)
2) Setting some (custom?) input AVCaptureDevice to grap audio playing in the background.

But how do I do it?

Answer (score -1):

Spotify, iTunes etc generally have the music encrypted and the keys protected via a DRM mechanism, so in theory you can't capture or record the music.

Even if you do find a workaround, without the rights for the music you will face copyright issues if this is for an app you want to make available to others, unfortunately.

Comment: 1) SnapChat does this, so I know it is possible supposedly by routing the background audio some way. 2) Copyright issues only apply if I distribute copyrighted music.

Comment: Well sort of! I'm really just giving you a heads up that you might invest a lot of effort in a solution and then find it blocked by the various app stores as they view it as infringing copyright. Audio is generally not as well protected as video in devices so it may be easier to find a workaround, but that won't really help you if the app store then blocks the app.

Comment: The conversation here is a little hard to follow as some of the comments have been deleted, but re Spotify: they do have the ability to do this, and you can also find 3rd party apps or techniques, but the licensing is still open as far as I am aware, and Spotify possibly have more leverage or relationships here than others. This was been looked at when it was launched - not sure what the latest is: http://www.completemusicupdate.com/article/snapchat-allows-music-capture-in-videos-is-it-licensed/. The point is just to make sure you are aware.